# can't find the file after packaging the app with electron packager

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I have my application in electron, it uses a file that generates certain values, which is running as a `child_process.spawn`. When it is in development, running with npm start, it works fine, but when i pack it with `electron packager` the problem appears, it turns out that the file i am calling cannot find it, with the error: `Error: spawn ./name_file ENOENT`. The file that is running with the spawn is a file that was created with C language.

Does anyone know how I can package it to work without having to change the spawn?

with this command i am packaging it.

```
electron-packager . system --platform linux --arch armv7l --out dist/ --overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

The path to your child process is properly not relative to your output directory `/dist`.

You should try to bundle your binary with your electron app.
[Bundle a precompiled binary or native file into an electron app.](https://medium.com/@ganeshrvel/bundle-a-precompiled-binary-or-native-file-into-an-electron-app-beacc44322a9)